# How can I get the date from the draggable vertical bar in timevis?

Tags: r, charts, shinyjs

I found the timevis package to be very useful for displaying time periods, and it is working as expected to display my data.

I have used the addCustomTime() function to add a draggable vertical line, which also works great, however, I find that I can't get the current value of that line.

The underlying js widget exposes functions to interact with the elements, but I haven't been able to access them successfully.  I have attempted to use shinyjs to catch the events emitted by the timeline, but I wasn't able to get that to work either.

I am fairly comfortable in R and shiny, but very much a newb in terms of the js, so I suspect I am just missing a trick on this.

In my ui.R, I create a timevisOutput object:

```
fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("timeline")
)
```

I am trying to listen to the "timechanged" event: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Events

When I add listeners with shinyjs in my server.R, I am able to see "mouseenter" events, but the "timechanged" handler doesn't seem to fire:

```
onevent("mouseenter", "timeline", print("timeline: mouseenter"))
onevent("timechanged", "timeline", print("Saw timechanged!"))
```

The visjs documentation has this snippet on "how to listen for a select event":

```
timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
  alert('selected items: ' + properties.items);
});
```

I tried adding that in a shinyjs::extendShinyjs() call, but that doesn't work either.  I added an example to listen for keydown events that did work:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { alert('Key pressed: ' + e.which); });
```

So that makes me think that I'm not referencing the timeline object correctly.  The $(document) in there makes me think that I'm not aware of a way to properly get at the timeline element.

Since I can see mouseenter events for the timeline, but can't see its timechanged events, I think I need the .on() call, however, I don't think I'm referencing the timeline element properly/.

**After @timelyportfolio's first response:**

That was a great write up, thanks!  I was able to confirm what the event looks; I have already been able to listen to the _selected event, but it's nice to see.

I am trying to get a custom time value, which uses a draggable line in the chart, it's added like this:

```
addCustomTime("mytimevis", Sys.Date(), "CustomTimeId")
```

The doc for the underlying javascript widget (http://visjs.org/docs/timeline), shows an event ("timechanged"), and a method ("getCustomTime()") to get access to its value, but I don't see the event in the trace, nor can I figure out how to make the method call work.

The "timechanged" event does not show up in the trace, which makes me think I need to make the .on() call from the widget's doc in order to enable that event:

```
timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
  alert('selected items: ' + properties.items);
});
```

I have been working to get that method call to work, since ideally I'd like to capture its change, and also if I can get that working, I should be able to get the getCustomTime() method working as well!

Comment: I will take a look if you can show some easily reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks @timelyportfolio.  I updated the question with some more specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### assumption

I will answer assuming that you would like to get the data in `R`.  If I assumed incorrectly, let me know and I will adjust.

#### message with shiny.trace

If you are not aware, one trick I often use is `options(shiny.trace=TRUE)` which will fill your screen with all the messages sent over the websocket.  Here is what I see when I run the following code.

```
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one"  , "Item two"  ,"Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA          ,           NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)

tv <- timevis(data)

# now let's see what messages we get in Shiny
library(shiny)
options(shiny.trace=TRUE)

ui <- timevisOutput("mytimevis")
server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$mytimevis <- renderTimevis({tv})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: screenshot of messsage from timevis on select]

I highlighted the messages pertaining to select.  This tells us we can observe or react to `mytimevis_selected`.

#### observe select event

Now, let's turn off `options(shiny.trace=FALSE)` and print in the `R` console when we receive a selected message.

```
options(shiny.trace=FALSE)

ui <- timevisOutput("mytimevis")
server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$mytimevis <- renderTimevis({tv})

  observeEvent(
    input$mytimevis_selected,
    {
      print(input$mytimevis_selected)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

#### add timechanged handler

Based on comments and re-reading your question, I now understand that you would like to add an event handler for [timechanged](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Events).  I think this code will help you over the hump.

```
library(timevis)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(magrittr)

tv <- timevis() %>%
  addCustomTime(Sys.Date() - 1, "yesterday") %>%
  # add an event handler since this is not one
  #   timevis provides
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
"
function(el,x) {
  // this will be our instance
  var tv = this.timeline;

  tv.on('timechanged', function(id, time) {
    //uncomment debugger if you want to stop here
    //debugger;
    Shiny.onInputChange(el.id + '_timechanged', {id:id, time:time})
  });
}
"
  )


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    timevisOutput("timeline"),
    actionButton("btn", "Add time bar 24 hours ago")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$timeline <- renderTimevis(
      tv
    )
    observeEvent(input$timeline_timechanged, {
      str(input$timeline_timechanged)
    })
  }
)
```

#### follow up

Please let me know if I headed down the wrong path or if none of this makes any sense.  I feel your pain, and troubleshooting this blend of technology can be very tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup!  I added a section to the question about what I am trying to accomplish now that you've moved me forward

Comment: will add to answer in about 30 seconds.

Comment: Fantastic, I really appreciate this!  Getting the event to work is one thing, but there's a lot of stuff to unpack in there that will be useful for me as I build this app, thank you!

Comment: let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I wrote the `timevis` package)

First of all: Kenton's answer is excellent, and OP's attempts were great as well.

This is more of an informational post.

#### Why what you tried didn't work

The reason `onevent("timechanged", ...)` doesn't work is because the `onevent()` function works for any standard javascript events, but it doesn't work for specific events that different plugins provide.

To bind a custom event such as that one, you'd have write some short custom javascript code. So looking at the visjs documentation and finding the `timeline.on('select', ...)` code is the correct path, but (as you suspected) you weren't referencing the timeline object correctly.

I made sure to export the actual underlying object just for this reason, so that people like you could manipulate it in its raw format. To access the timeline object from timevis, you use `$(id)[0].widget.timeline`. Since the id of your timeline is `timeline` and you wanted to call the `on()` function, then you can do something like `$("#timeline")[0].widget.timeline.on('select', ...)`.

#### Why this functionality doesn't exist

When I looked at the documentation of visjs I decided to have 4 events that the widget would export to shiny automatically whenever they changed: the data, the selected items, the IDs of all items, and the currently visible time window.  I decided not to use the `on('timechanged')` event because it behaved differently from all the rest: it would only return one item at a time.

What do I mean by that? For example, `input$timeline_data` always returns the entire data in this moment; `input$timeline_select` always tells you what are all the selected items at this moment; `input$timeline_timechanged` would get fired every time a different vertical bar gets dragged, and therefore will contain only the last dragged bar, not all of them, and it wouldn't give you a way to ask for the time in one specific bar. Does that make sense?

Of course it's possible to write some code that keeps track of all the bars, but that gets very messy very quickly (for example, it'd have to make sure to get updated when a bar is added/removed). So I chose to not go down that rabbithole.

Comment: @timelyportfolio as I said, great answer

Comment: one note, the `timeline` widget will not be available until after render, so I would suggest using `onRender` to insure it is set up rather than in a bare script.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point to clarify. Actually, I was wondering about this for a while: is there a JS event that gets triggered when an htmlwidget gets rendered, so that we can capture it in pure javascript without having to go through the htmlwidget onRender?

Comment: didn't think so and just checked repo to make sure.  I don't see anything.  Now, I am wondering if I should emit events for initialize, render, and resize for all my `htmlwidgets`.  Right now, I think `onRender` will be by far the best option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further clarification @daattali; when learning a new technology, combing through examples often glosses over some of the specific gaps in knowledge when moving on to development, so both of these answers have been very helpful.

Comment: @timelyportfolio yes onRender definitely gets the job done. And it's awesome. But I do think it'd be a good idea for htmlwidgets to also trigger that as a JS event